# Extract HTTP Status Code from java.io.IOException

Tags: java, http, ioexception, http-status-codes

How is it possible (if at all) to get the HTTP status code from a `java.io.IOException in java`
?

Comment: What status code are you talking about? Are you talking about some `IOException` subclass that contains a status code?

Comment: language? example?

Comment: Language is written in the tags: Java

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: I see no mention whatsoever of a status code in [java.io.Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html).

Comment: HttpURLConnection throws java.io.IOException when there is an http status code that is an error. So faced with such an exception, I don't think it is unreasonable to ask "how to get the HTTP status code". Though the question is terse, google did take me straight here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming this is about an `IOException` thrown by a `URLConnection`.

Three possibilities to handle this, depending on your restrictions.

**1) Cast your `URLConnection` to a `HttpURLConnection` and call `getResponseCode`**

If you have access to the connection object, you can get the status code using this code:

```
int statusCode = (HttpURLConnection)theConnection).getResponseCode();
```

**2) Use a `HttpURLConnection` instead of an `URLConnection` in the first place**

If you can do this, it would be the best solution, because an `URLConnection` doesn't throw on error status codes. You can just call `getResponseCode` and check the status without getting any exception first.

**3) Parse the exception message itself**

The `IOException`'s message usually looks like this:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://something
```

So you can just use a regex (or simple string manipulation) to get the response code out of there.

Note that for status 404, the message doesn't look like this and a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown. I'm not sure if there are any other status codes throwing "special" exceptions like this, but watch out for this.

**Example code demonstrating methods 2 & 3:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void testUrl(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException {
        URLConnection conn = null;
        System.out.println("Testing URL " + urlString);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            conn = url.openConnection();

            // Just to make the exception happen
            conn.getInputStream();

            System.out.println("Success!");
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
            System.out.println();

            // Method 2 with access to the URLConnection object
            // (Method 1 would have been having the connection as HttpURLConnection from the beginning.)
            int responseCode = 0;
            System.out.println("Trying method 2 to get status code");

            try {
                if(conn != null) {
                    // Casting to HttpURLConnection allows calling getResponseCode
                    responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection)conn).getResponseCode();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("conn variable not set");
                }
            } catch(IOException ex2) {
                System.out.println("getResponseCode threw: " + ex2);
            }

            System.out.println("Status code from calling getResponseCode: " + responseCode);
            System.out.println();

            // Method 3 without access to the URLConnection object
            responseCode = 0;
            System.out.println("Trying method 3 to get status code");

            // First we try parsing the exception message to see if it contains the response code
            Matcher exMsgStatusCodeMatcher = Pattern.compile("^Server returned HTTP response code: (\\d+)").matcher(ex.getMessage());
            if(exMsgStatusCodeMatcher.find()) {
                responseCode = Integer.parseInt(exMsgStatusCodeMatcher.group(1));
            } else if(ex.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("FileNotFoundException")) {
                // 404 is a special case because it will throw a FileNotFoundException instead of having "404" in the message
                System.out.println("Got a FileNotFoundException");
                responseCode = 404;
            } else {
                // There can be other types of exceptions not handled here
                System.out.println("Exception (" + ex.getClass().getSimpleName() + ") doesn't contain status code: " + ex);
            }

            System.out.println("Status code from parsing exception message: " + responseCode);
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("-------");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws MalformedURLException {
        testUrl("https://httpbin.org/status/200");
        testUrl("https://httpbin.org/status/404");
        testUrl("https://httpbin.org/status/403");
        testUrl("http://nonexistingsite1111111.com");
    }
}
```

Output of the example code:

```
Testing URL https://httpbin.org/status/200                                                                                                                                                                                        
Success!                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-------                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

Testing URL https://httpbin.org/status/404                                                                                                                                                                                        
Error!                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

Trying method 2 to get status code                                                                                                                                                                                                
Status code from calling getResponseCode: 404                                                                                                                                                                                     

Trying method 3 to get status code                                                                                                                                                                                                
Got a FileNotFoundException                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Status code from parsing exception message: 404                                                                                                                                                                                   

-------

Testing URL https://httpbin.org/status/403                                                                                                                                                                                        
Error!                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

Trying method 2 to get status code                                                                                                                                                                                                
Status code from calling getResponseCode: 403                                                                                                                                                                                     

Trying method 3 to get status code                                                                                                                                                                                                
Status code from parsing exception message: 403                                                                                                                                                                                   

-------

Testing URL http://nonexistingsite1111111.com                                                                                                                                                                                     
Error!                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

Trying method 2 to get status code                                                                                                                                                                                                
getResponseCode threw: java.net.UnknownHostException: nonexistingsite1111111.com                                                                                                                                                  
Status code from calling getResponseCode: 0                                                                                                                                                                                       

Trying method 3 to get status code                                                                                                                                                                                                
Exception (UnknownHostException) doesn't contain status code: java.net.UnknownHostException: nonexistingsite1111111.com                                                                                                           
Status code from parsing exception message: 0                                                                                                                                                                                     

-------
```

Comment: Can you explain how "You can just call getResponseCode and check the status without getting any exception first." applies to option 2 but not option 1? If you can cast the URLConnection to an HttpURLConnection, then it *was* an HttpURLConnection "in the first place" and the fact that it's been delivered to you as a URLConnection doesn't change that?

Comment: It applies to both - read my option 1 again ;) I just meant that you can either create it as HttpURLConnection in the first place or cast it to one later. In both cases, you can call getResponseCode.